# How do I reach a data that is on my Django website's url

Tags: python, html, django, forms, get

I am developing a Python-Django website and want to take input from the user and use it. So i could use this code in my HTML page:

```
 <form method="get">
    <fieldset><legend>Form</legend>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Name </td><td><input type="text" name="name"> </td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Thus, could get a link ending with the input. But how do I use that input on my tag.py or even other HTML pages? Would be glad if someone helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create form and then place it in table cell.

[Read documentation about Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/)